# How to replace part of text in a column of a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: excel, pandas, replace

I use Pandas to modify Excel workbooks.

The question is:
I need to replace ONLY parts of text of a row, leaving the rest of text the same.
(for sure every Excel workbook is different, so values are different)

For instance, I have this table:

**Column A**

**0**  "This equipment list is only valid"

**1**  "Please enter the demand quantity"

**2**  "Please enter Sales Agreement"

I want to replace the word "enter" with "specify", to have this result:

**Column A**

**0**  "This equipment list is only valid"

**1**  "Please specify the demand quantity"

**2**  "Please specify Sales Agreement"

I tryed the following pandas.DataFrame.replace,

`df.replace(to_replace='^*enter.*', '*specify.*', regex=True)`

`df.replace("enter", "TESTED", regex=True)`

but I´m not able to do it.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['column A'] = df['column A'].str.replace("enter","specify")
```